# restart python script after quitting

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt, debian

I have a python3 script which contains GUI written in PyQt.
The main GUI script `qtdesign.py` calls upon other another interface. When the interface runs an error, I have subprocess `error.py` that pops up with an error message over `qtdesign.py`.

Now, when this happens, I want to quit `error.py` and  `qtdesign.py` with `qApp.quit()` and AUTOMATICALLY restart `qtdesign.py` over again.

For clarification:

`qtdesign.py` --> `[error]` --> `error.py` --> `[QUIT error.py & qtdesign.py (qApp.quit())]` --> automatically restart `qtdesign.py`

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576911-keep-a-process-up-and-running/ 

I found this link, but can't quite figure out how to use it.

Comment: You could use `os.execl` after the qapplication exec returns. [see here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/260268/restart-your-python-program)

Comment: May I clarify? After qtdesign crash do you want automatically stop error.py or error.py stops by themself?

Comment: `error.py` stops them by itself. My questions is how do I start up `qtdesign.py` up again?

Comment: @avelampudi. Why is *error.py* started by `subprocesss`? Why doesn't *qtdesign.py* show the error itself?

Comment: there's a LOT of underlying code and other parts of the code that I left out. essentially, the error is created in another thread (not the GUI thread), so I needed to start error.py through a subprocess.

Comment: @avelampudi. Just send the error back to the main thread using a signal. There's no need for a separate process.